# t-sql 'at time zone' does not know all of the timezones that .net knows about

Tags: .net, sql-server, timezone

My user interface features a dropdown list of all of the timezones populated by .Net's TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() (in MVC Razor) that is then recorded against the user.

```
            <select id="TimeZoneAbbreviation" name="TimeZoneAbbreviation">
                @foreach (var tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
                {
                    <!option value="@tz.StandardName" @(tz.StandardName == Model.Project.TimeZone ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@tz.DisplayName</!option>
                }
            </select>
```

I have a stored procedure that needs to do some processing and convert a UTC time that something is logged in the database into the current user's local time for presentation on the screen.

In testing, I discovered that a handful (16) timezones cause 'at time zone' to throw an error.  These problems occur on both SQL Azure and Sql Server 2016

```
declare @timezone as varchar(max) = 'Alaskan Standard Time'
select cast(cast(GETUTCDATE() as datetimeoffset) at time zone @timeZone as datetime) -- this works

set @timezone = 'Cabo Verde Standard Time'
select cast(cast(GETUTCDATE() as datetimeoffset) at time zone @timeZone as datetime) -- does not work

set @timezone = 'Coordinated Universal Time'
select cast(cast(GETUTCDATE() as datetimeoffset) at time zone @timeZone as datetime) -- does not work
```

This results in

```
(1 row affected)
Msg 9820, Level 16, State 1, Line 411
The time zone parameter 'Cabo Verde Standard Time' provided to AT TIME ZONE clause is invalid.
Msg 9820, Level 16, State 1, Line 414
The time zone parameter 'Coordinated Universal Time' provided to AT TIME ZONE clause is invalid.
```

So I discover that SQL has its own list that is different to that of .Net. So the immediate thought to not use .Net to get the list. Rather, I should simply ask SQL Server via a query.

```
select * from sys.time_zone_info
```

The problem with this approach is that this returns a different and incompatible list to that of .Net.  In my .Net code I have some code like this

```
TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString(project.TimeZone)
```

This will break if it uses an unknown string that SQL Server knows about.

> Fun fact #1, the documentation at
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
>   states that the list is sourced from
>   "KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time
>   Zones". Sure enough, 'Coordinated Universal Time' is not in the list
>   (and it does not work).  But  'Cabo Verde Standard Time' IS in the
>   list (but that does not work either).
>
> Fun fact #2, "Cabo Verde Standard" does not work but "Cape Verde
>   Standard Time" does work.  These are not typos. These are actual
>   timezones.
>
> (Before someone asks, I converted the GetUTCDate() into a
>   datetimeoffset as the documentation says "If inputdate is provided as
>   a datetimeoffset value, then AT TIME ZONE clause converts it into the
>   target time zone using the time zone conversion rules." which is what
>   I wanted to happen).

So, the question...  what am I to do?  What have others done?  This whole area appears to be a total dog's breakfast.

I guess my problem is that I have timezone processing both in the stored procs and .Net and their timezone processing is incompatible.  I probably should somehow just do one and not the other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *real* problem is that nobody uses Windows timezone names. Everyone uses IANA timezone names making the `at time zone` clause a bit ... unhelpful.

In this case you should probably use the ID, not the DisplayName. For example, the display name `Cabo Verde Daylight Time` has an ID of `Cape Verde Standard Time`. The name `Coordinated Universal Time` has an ID of `UTC`.

BTW in my case, on SQL Server 2017 on Windows 10, I get 139 timezone names

**Update**

I forgot to add that Matt Johnson created a [SQLCLR UDF](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) that adds support for the IANA timezones through Noda Time. If you're serious about timezones you should probably use it instead of `AT TIME ZONE`

Comment: You are right. When I changed the razor code to "Id" from "StandardName" it made it better but there were still differences. SQL had "UTC+13" and .Net "UTC-13" <facepalm/> SQL also had "Dateline Standard Time" but this does not even exist in .Net.  I am just going to do all timezone calcs through SQL Server. Thanks!

Comment: @DJA - Using the `Id` is correct. SQL uses the same exact mechanism and data as .Net.  If you are finding differences, then one of your machines is behind on OS updates.  (Time zones change over time, thanks to governments.)

Comment: However, "UTC+13" and "Dateline Standard Time" are valid and have been there several years.  "UTC-13" is not a valid ID at all, and never has been.  If .net is actually returning that ID, then someone has messed with the registry.  I'd run Windows Update on that computer asap.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint my opinion on `AT TIME ZONE` remains the same. Especially on Linux/MacOS which *don't* use the Windows time zones.

Comment: Agreed.  It would be better if it had support for IANA zones built in. :)

Comment: My bad "&#x2B;" is "+" not "-".  Rookie error. Ignore the "UTC-13" comment as it was supposed to me "UTC+13"

Comment: Please vote for IANA time zone support in SQL Server [Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40198465-support-iana-time-zone-identifiers-with-at-time-zo).  Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server feedback now appears to be [Here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/0c4aa68b-7c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)